# Show that along the cycloid, the tangent vector is not well-definded when $\theta=2k\pi$.

Tags: differential-geometry

> Show that along the cycloid, the tangent vector is not well-defined when $\theta=2k\pi$.
>
> p.s. : A cycloid has the parametrization $\bf{r}$$(\theta)=(\theta-\sin\theta,1-\cos \theta)$.

Actually I don't understand what "not well-defined" means in this case. I understand there'll be a sharp bent on that point, but how should I present it? Thanks.

Comment: There is not a unique straight line tangent to the curve at that point. It's like the cusp of $x \mapsto \sqrt{\lvert x\rvert}$.

Comment: I find that the slope of the tangent is cotπ, which is undefined, but seems this is not enough.

Comment: The derivative of the parametrisation in $2k\pi$ is $0$. Whenever a curve has derivative $0$ somewhere, defining a tangent to the curve at that point is problematic. If you can reparametrise so that the differential at that point becomes nonzero, it was a pseudo-problem. Here, we have a change of direction at those points, coming in, the point moves (in the limit) vertically downward, going out, vertically upward. If you define the direction of a curve by $e(t) = \frac{1}{\lVert \gamma'(t)\rVert}\gamma'(t)$, then $e(t)$ has a discontinuity here in the zeros of $\gamma'$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Showing something isn't a manifold](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231892/showing-something-isnt-a-manifold)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I find that the slope of the tangent is cotπ, which is undefined, but seems this is not enough.

Correct: this is not enough. There is nothing wrong with vertical tangent lines. In general, it's advisable to avoid the slope-intercept equation of lines when studying differential geometry. It concerns statements that are independent of coordinates chosen on a plane, or on a manifold. The slope being infinite depends on coordinate system

> how should I present it?

In a manner consistent with how tangent vectors were presented to you. There are multiple ways to present the material of differential geometry. Those not taking the same class do not know which one was chosen by the professor.

To say that an *something* is not-defined means: it is not true that there exists a (unique) object that satisfies the definition of *something*. So, the first thing to locate is the definition of a tangent vector of a curve used in the course.

Here is one of several possible definitions: if the limit 
$$\lim_{t\to t_0} \frac{r(t)-r(t_0)}{|r(t)-r(t_0)|}\operatorname{sign}(t-t_0)  \tag1$$
exists as $t\to t_0$, the value of this limit is the unit tangent vector of at $r(t_0)$.

The above definition agrees with $r'(t_0)/|r'(t_0)|$ when the derivative exists and is nonzero. However, (1) is more general: it allows us to find the tangent vector even when the parametrization has zero derivative -- provided that the tangent vector exists.

It is not hard to check that (1) does not exist for the cycloid: the one-sided limits have different values $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$.

Comment: But there are always two unit tangent vectors to a curve, the normalised velocity vector r'(t)/||r'(t)||, and its opposite. In this case, you could therefore chose the left value as (0,1) and the right value as -(0,-1)=(0,1), which is the same. I.e., in this case, it is possible to find a continuous mapping between t and a unit tangent at all points of the cycloid, so long as we are happy to assign (0,1) or (0,-1) to the cusp itself...